# How to insert data into the first row of the databse mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a query that should insert data into the first row of data in the database but for some reason it does nothing. The only reason why I can think it doesn't work is because there is nothing in the table. Even so I declare what should happen if NULL.

Here is my code:

```
foreach ($player_fromsite as $match_player_in_game) {
    $querytwo = 'UPDATE `'.$tablename.'` SET `'.$match_player_in_game.'`="'.'yes'.'" WHERE `'.$match_player_in_game.'` IS NULL ORDER BY `'.$match_player_in_game.'` ASC LIMIT 1';

    for ($a = 0; $a < 11; $a++) {
        if ($match_player_in_game == $home_players[$a]) {
            // Insert a row of information into the table "example"
            mysql_query($querytwo) or die(mysql_error());
        } else {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Insert and update are 2 different things.

Comment: [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/update.html) does not insert data; it just *modifies* existing data.  You want to use [`INSERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert.html) instead: the clue is in the name!  :)

Comment: I tried insert but can't limit it to 1. $querytwo = 'INSERT INTO `'.$tablename.'` '.' (`'.$match_player_in_game.'`) '.'VALUES'.'("' . 'yes' . '")' LIMIT 1;   This doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean "*limit it to 1*"? `LIMIT` is not a valid keyword in the `INSERT` syntax (see the manual link in my previous comment).  `INSERT` will only insert (at most) the number of records for which you provide `VALUES`.  If you only provide one set of values, at most one record will be inserted.

Comment: There are numerous guides and tutorials of how to achieve this. Besides, changing UPDATE to INSERT is not enough.. there's a different syntax in what follows, please read how things work before asking why they don't work. We'll be glad to help then.

Comment: Can you please assist since I have searched already and haven't found an answer to update the nth row

Answer (score 1):

The `UPDATE` clause will update any matching records. If there are no records you need to `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (aField,otherField) VALUES ("Foo","Bar");
```

Or to insert more than one record you can use the batch form:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (aField,otherField) VALUES ("Foo","Bar"),("Second Foo","Second Bar");
```